# Symfony 5.3 new authentication doesn't keep my authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication

I'm triyng to use the new authenticator manager proposed by Symfony 5.3. I follow the lesson of Symfonycasts. I just changed the UserIdentifier to 'username' instead of 'email', following the habits of my users.

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Security;

    use App\Entity\User;
    use App\Repository\UserRepository;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UserNotFoundException;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractAuthenticator;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\RememberMeBadge;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\CustomCredentials;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;

    class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
    {

        use TargetPathTrait;

        private UserRepository $userRepository;
        private RouterInterface $router;

        public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository, RouterInterface $router)
        {
            $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
            $this->router = $router;
        }

        public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
        {
            return ($request->getPathInfo() === '/login' &&         $request->isMethod('POST'));
        }
       public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
       {
           $username = $request->request->get('_username');
           $password = $request->request->get('_password');

            return new Passport(
                new UserBadge($username, function($userIdentifier) {
            $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['username' => $userIdentifier]);

                    if (!$user) {
                        throw new UserNotFoundException();
            }
            return $user;
        }),
        new PasswordCredentials($password),
        [

            new CsrfTokenBadge(
               'authenticate',
               $request->request->get('_csrf_token')
           ),
           new RememberMeBadge(),
            ]

            );
        }
        public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
        {
           return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('core_home'));
        }
        public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
        {
            $request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);
            return new RedirectResponse(
                $this->router->generate('login')
            );
        }
    }
```

According to the logs, the authentication succeed :

```
    Nov 11 10:22:24 |INFO | SECURI Authenticator successful!         authenticator="App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator" token={"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\Token\\PostAuthenticationToken":"PostAuthenticationToken(user=\"denis.picard48@orange.fr\", authenticated=true, roles=\"ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN, ROLE_USER\")"}
    Nov 11 10:22:24 |DEBUG| SECURI Clearing remember-me cookie. name="REMEMBERME"
    Nov 11 10:22:24 |DEBUG| SECURI Remember-me was requested; setting cookie. 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI The "App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator" authenticator set the response. Any later authenticator will not be called authenticator="App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI Stored the security token in the session. key="_security_main"
```

After the authentication, the system store the informations in the sessions

```
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT DATABASE() 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS Field, COLUMN_TYPE AS Type, IS_NULLABLE AS `Null`, COLUMN_KEY AS `Key`, COLUMN_DEFAULT AS `Default`, EXTRA AS Extra, COLUMN_COMMENT AS Comment, CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS CharacterSet, COLLATION_NAME AS Collation FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'olymphys_odpf' AND TABLE_NAME = 'doctrine_migration_versions' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT DATABASE() 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT DISTINCT k.`CONSTRAINT_NAME`, k.`COLUMN_NAME`, k.`REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`, k.`REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` /*!50116 , c.update_rule, c.delete_rule */ FROM information_schema.key_column_usage k /*!50116 INNER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints c ON   c.constraint_name = k.constraint_name AND   c.table_name = 'doctrine_migration_versions' */ WHERE k.table_name = 'doctrine_migration_versions' AND k.table_schema = 'olymphys_odpf' /*!50116 AND c.constraint_schema = 'olymphys_odpf' */ AND k.`REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` is not NULL 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT DATABASE() 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT NON_UNIQUE AS Non_Unique, INDEX_NAME AS Key_name, COLUMN_NAME AS Column_Name, SUB_PART AS Sub_Part, INDEX_TYPE AS Index_Type FROM information_schema.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'doctrine_migration_versions' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'olymphys_odpf' ORDER BY SEQ_IN_INDEX ASC 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT ENGINE, AUTO_INCREMENT, TABLE_COLLATION, TABLE_COMMENT, CREATE_OPTIONS FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'doctrine_migration_versions' 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT * FROM doctrine_migration_versions 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT DATABASE() 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| PHP    127.0.0.1:40890 Closing 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |INFO | SERVER POST (302) /login host="127.0.0.1:8004" ip="127.0.0.1" scheme="https"
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| PHP    127.0.0.1:40894 Accepted path="/usr/bin/php7.4" php="7.4.7"
```

But, the return of this successful authentication, towards my route (core_home) works, and I'm no more authenticated :

```
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |INFO | REQUES Matched route "core_home". method="GET" request_uri="https://localhost:8000/" route="core_home" route_parameters={"_controller":"App\\Controller\\CoreController::index","_route":"core_home"}
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI Checking for authenticator support. authenticators=2 firewall_name="main"
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI Checking support on authenticator. authenticator="App\\Security\\LoginFormAuthenticator"
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI Authenticator does not support the request. 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI Checking support on authenticator. authenticator="Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\RememberMeAuthenticator"
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI Remember-me cookie detected. 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |INFO | PHP    User Deprecated: Since symfony/http-kernel 5.3: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\KernelEvent::isMasterRequest()" is deprecated, use "isMainRequest()" instead. 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI Read existing security token from the session. key="_security_main" token_class="Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\Token\\PostAuthenticationToken"
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| DOCTRI SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.username AS username_2, t0.roles AS roles_3, t0.password AS password_4, t0.email AS email_5, t0.is_active AS is_active_6, t0.token AS token_7, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at_8, t0.rne AS rne_9, t0.nom AS nom_10, t0.prenom AS prenom_11, t0.adresse AS adresse_12, t0.ville AS ville_13, t0.code AS code_14, t0.phone AS phone_15, t0.createdAt AS createdAt_16, t0.updatedAt AS updatedAt_17, t0.lastVisit AS lastVisit_18, t0.civilite AS civilite_19, t0.centre_id AS centre_id_20, t0.autorisationphotos_id AS autorisationphotos_id_21, t0.rne_id_id AS rne_id_id_22 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ? 0=1
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI Cannot refresh token because user has changed. provider="Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Security\\User\\EntityUserProvider" username="denis.picard48@orange.fr"
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI Token was deauthenticated after trying to refresh it. 
    Nov 11 10:22:25 |DEBUG| SECURI Clearing remember-me cookie. name="REMEMBERME"
```

The system said I changed the user. But HE does that !!

edit at 18h26 : What I understand is that when the authenticator say Authenticator succesful, it store in the PostAuthenticationToken my email as UserIdentifier instead of my username (like I want)(see the first line of the logs, here). And when it compare it with the data, it's wrong ! And the user changed...

There is my User entity class :

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Entity;

    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use App\Repository\UserRepository;
    use Doctrine\Common\Proxy\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;



    /**
     * /**
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
     * @ORM\Table(name="user")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Cet email est déjà enregistré en base.")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Cet identifiant est déjà enregistré en base")
     */
    class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface, \Serializable
    {


        /**
         * @ORM\Id()
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, unique=true)
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @Assert\Length(max=50)
         */
        private $username;

         /**
          * @ORM\Column(type="array")
         */
        private $roles;

        /**
         * @var string The hashed password
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        private $password;


        private $plainPassword;

         /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
        * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @Assert\Length(max=60)
         * @Assert\Email()
         */
        private $email;

         /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean", nullable=true)
         */
        private $isActive;

        /**
         * @var string le token qui servira lors de l'oubli de mot de passe
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $token;

         /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
         * @var \DateTime
         */
        private $passwordRequestedAt;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="rne", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $rne;

         /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $nom;
        
         /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255,                 nullable=true)
         */
        protected $prenom;  

         /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="adresse", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $adresse;

         /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="ville", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $ville;

         /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $code;

         /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=15, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $phone;

         /**
           *  
           * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Centrescia")
           * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="centre_id",  referencedColumnName="id" )
           */       
        private $centrecia;

         /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="createdAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        private $createdAt;

         /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="updatedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        private $updatedAt;

         /**
         * @var \DateTime
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="lastVisit", type="datetime", nullable=true)
         */
        private $lastVisit;

         /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="civilite", type="string", length=15, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $civilite;

        /**
           *  
           * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Fichiersequipes", cascade={"persist"})
           * @ORM\JoinColumn( referencedColumnName="id", )
           */
         private $autorisationphotos;

         /**
          * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Equipes::class, mappedBy="hote")
          */
         private $interlocuteur;

         /**
          * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Rne")
          */
         private $rneId;

        public function __toString(): ?string
        {
            return $this->prenom.' '.$this->getNom();
        }

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->isActive = true;
            $this->roles = ['ROLE_USER'];

        }

        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
}

        /**
         * A visual identifier that represents this user.
         *
         * @see UserInterface
         */
        public function getUsername(): string
        {
            return (string) $this->username;
        }

        public function setUsername(string $username): self
        {
            $this->username = $username;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * The public representation of the user (e.g. a username, an email address, etc.)
         *
         * @see UserInterface
         */
        public function getUserIdentifier(): string
        {
            return (string) $this->email;
        }

         /*
         * Get email
         */
        public function getCentrecia()
        {
    return $this->centrecia;
        }

        /*
         * Set CentreCia
         */
        public function setCentrecia($centrecia): User
        {
            $this->centrecia= $centrecia;
            return $this;
        }

        /*
         * Get email
         */
        public function getEmail()
        {
            return $this->email;
        }

        /*
         * Set email
         */
        public function setEmail($email)
        {
            $this->email = $email;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getToken(): string
        {
            return $this->token;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $token
         */
        public function setToken(?string $token): void
        {
            $this->token = $token;
        }

        /**
         * @see UserInterface
         */
        public function getRoles(): array
        {
            $roles = $this->roles;
            // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

            return array_unique($roles);
        }

        public function setRoles(array $roles): self
        {

            if (!in_array('ROLE_USER', $roles))
            {
                $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
            }
            foreach ($roles as $role)
            {
                if(substr($role, 0, 5) !== 'ROLE_') {
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Chaque rôle doit commencer par 'ROLE_'");
                }
            }
            $this->roles = $roles;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
         */
        public function getPassword(): string
        {
            return $this->password;
        }

        public function setPassword(string $password): self
        {
            $this->password = $password;

            return $this;
        }
        /*
         * Get isActive
         */
        public function getIsActive()
        {
            return $this->isActive;
        }

        /*
         * Set isActive
         */
        public function setIsActive($isActive)
        {
            $this->isActive = $isActive;
            return $this;
        }
        /**
         * @see UserInterface
         */
        public function getSalt()
        {
            // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
        }

        /**
         * @see UserInterface
         */
        public function eraseCredentials()
        {
            // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
             $this->plainPassword = null;
}

        /*
         * Get passwordRequestedAt
         */
        public function getPasswordRequestedAt()
        {
            return $this->passwordRequestedAt;
        }

        /*
         * Set passwordRequestedAt
         */
       public function         setPasswordRequestedAt($passwordRequestedAt)
        {
            $this->passwordRequestedAt = $passwordRequestedAt;
            return $this;
        }

        /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
        public function serialize()
        {
            return serialize(array(
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
                $this->isActive,
                // voir remarques sur salt plus haut
                // $this->salt,
            ));
        }

        /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
        public function unserialize($serialized)
        {
            list (
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
                $this->isActive,
                // voir remarques sur salt plus haut
                // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
        }

            /**
         * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"registration"})
        * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
         */

        public function getPlainPassword(): ?string
        {
            return $this->plainPassword;
        }

        public function setPlainPassword(string $plainPassword): self
        {
            $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
            return $this;
        }

         /**
         * Set rne
         *
         * @param string $rne
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setRne( $rne) {
            $this->rne= $rne;

            return $this;
    } 
        /**
         * Get Adresse
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getAdresse() {
            return $this->adresse;
        }
        /**
         * Set adresse
         *
         * @param string $adresse
 *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setAdresse( $adresse) {
            $this->adresse= $adresse;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get ville
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getVille() {
            return $this->ville;
        }
        /**
         * Set ville
         *
         * @param string $ville
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setVille( $ville) {
            $this->ville= $ville;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get code
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getCode() {
            return $this->code;
        }
        /**
         * Set Code
         *
         * @param string $code
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setCode( $code) {
            $this->code= $code;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get 
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getCivilite() {
            return $this->civilite;
        }
        /**
         * Set civilite
         *
         * @param string $civilite
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setCivilite( $civilite) {
            $this->civilite= $civilite;

            return $this;
        }
         /**
         * Get phone
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPhone() {
            return $this->phone;
        }
        /**
         * Set phone
         *
         * @param string $code
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setPhone( $phone) {
            $this->phone= $phone;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get rne
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getRne() {
            return $this->rne;
        }




        /**
         * Get nom
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getNom() {
            return $this->nom;
        }
        /**
         * Set nom
         *
         * @param string $nom
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setNom( $nom) {
            $this->nom= $nom;

            return $this;
        }


        /**
         * Get prenom
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPrenom() {
            return $this->prenom;
        }
        /**
         * Set prenom
         *
         * @param string $prenom
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setPrenom( $prenom) {
            $this->prenom= $prenom;

            return $this;
        }

         /*
         * Get createdAt
         */
        public function getCreatedAt()
        {
            return $this->createdAt;
        }

        /*
         * Set updatedAt
         */
        public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
        {
            $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
            return $this;
        }

        /*
         * Get updatedAt
         */
        public function getUpdatedAt()
        {
            return $this->updatedAt;
        }

        /*
         * Set updatedAt
         */
        public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
        {
            $this->updatedAt =$updatedAt;
            return $this;
        }

         /* Get lastVisit
        */
        public function getLastVisit()
        {
            return $this->lastVisit;
        }

       /*
         * Set lastVisit
         */
        public function setLastVisit($lastVisit)
        {
            $this->lastVisit = $lastVisit;
            return $this;
        }
         public function getAutorisationphotos()
        {
            return $this->autorisationphotos;
       }


        public function setAutorisationphotos($autorisation)
        {
           $this->autorisationphotos = $autorisation;

            return $this;
        }
        public function getNomPrenom()
        {
            return $this->nom.' '.$this->prenom;
    
        }

         public function getPrenomNom()
        {
            return $this->prenom.' '.$this->nom;
    
        }

        /**
         * @return Collection|Equipes[]
         */
        public function getInterlocuteur(): Collection
        {
            return $this->interlocuteur;
        }

        public function addInterlocuteur(Equipes $interlocuteur): self
        {
            if (!$this->interlocuteur->contains($interlocuteur))         {
                $this->interlocuteur[] = $interlocuteur;
               $interlocuteur->setHote($this);
            }

            return $this;
        }

        public function removeInterlocuteur(Equipes $interlocuteur): self
        {
            if ($this->interlocuteur->removeElement($interlocuteur)) {
                // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
                if ($interlocuteur->getHote() === $this) {
                    $interlocuteur->setHote(null);
                }
            }

            return $this;
        }

        public function getRneId(): ?rne
        {
            return $this->rneId;
        }

        public function setRneId(?rne $rneId): self
        {
            $this->rneId = $rneId;

            return $this;
        }






    }
```

Comment: Can you show your User entity class?

Comment: @PatrickKenekayoro : thank you ! my error was in the User Identity : I forgot getUserIdentifier : return (string) $this->email; instead of username ! Everythings works fine now !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my answer to the comment of Patrickkenekayoro, I forgot a change in the `User` entity: The `getUserIdentifier()` function should bring back the `username`, instead of the `email`.

Comment: Yes this totaly solved the problem. I was returning something else. (getId) so authentication was wrong. thanks